# Using TVPosterView inside UICollectionViewCell creates odd sizing issue

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I'm trying to create a tvOS project using `UICollectionView` displays camera streams.

In the `UICollectionViewCell` I'm using `TVPosterView` to display the stream/image and a title.

The problem that I'm facing currently that when the app starts all thumbnails/`UICollectionViewCell` seems to have proper size; First item focused with larger size than others. When I roll-out to other item/s, the earlier focused item became much smaller than the size it has when started.

Let me try to explain the situation if I'm not clear with my words.

When the app starts - `Camera A` focused and larger size than others:

[image]

When roll-out `Camera A`, it become much smaller than `Camera D` or `Camera E`; Also, the currently focused `Camera B` do not has a larger size anymore (if I compared with `Camera A` size from previous screen):

[image]

In the `UICollectionView` controller I have following delegate method:

```
extension ListingViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let thumbWidth = CGFloat(320)
        let thumbHeight = CGFloat(thumbWidth * 0.7)
        return CGSize(width: thumbWidth, height: thumbHeight)
    }
}
```

In the `UICollectionViewCell` I basically has following codes:

```
internal func setupUI()
{
        posterView = TVPosterView()
        posterView.tag = 1100
        posterView.clipsToBounds = false
        
        addSubview(posterView)
        posterView.alignToSuperView()
}
```

alignToSuperView() basically an extension to `UIView` with following codes:

```
public func alignToSuperView()
{
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        guard let margins = self.superview?.layoutMarginsGuide else {
            return
        }
        self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```